# Calling FORTRAN dll from C# and assigning values to array of structures

Tags: c#, interop, struct, fortran

I can pass a `C#` struct into `FORTRAN` just fine. I can even pass an array of a `C#` struct as an array of `TYPE()` in `FORTRAN`. Where I run into trouble is when I tried to return values back into `C#`. Here is an example:

The fortran dll is:

```
MODULE TESTING

   TYPE VALUEREF
     INTEGER*4 :: A
   ENDTYPE VALUEREF

CONTAINS

   SUBROUTINE TEST_REF(T,N)
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: TEST_REF
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'TEST_REF' :: TEST_REF
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: N
   IMPLICIT NONE
     INTEGER*4 :: A,I,N   
     TYPE(VALUEREF) :: T(N)      
     A = 100
     DO I=1,N
        T(I)%A = A + I
     END DO

   END SUBROUTINE
END MODULE
```

and the `C#` calling function that expects results is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ValueRef
{
    public int a;
}

[DllImport("mathlib.dll")]
static extern void TEST_REF(ValueRef[] t, int n);

void Main()
{
    ValueRef[] T = new ValueRef[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < T.Length; i++)
    {
        T[i].a = i;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Initialize");
    for (int i = 0; i < T.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  A={0}", T[i].a);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Call Fortran");
    TEST_REF(T, T.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < T.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  A={0}", T[i].a);
    }
}
```

With results:

```
Initialize
  A=0
  A=1
  A=2
  A=3
Call Fortran
  A=0
  A=1
  A=2
  A=3
```

Debugging through the FORTRAN code, I see the initial values pass from `C#` to `FORTRAN` just fine. The the values get overridden with new values and control is passed back into `C#` where the old values are still contained within the `ValueRef` instances.

Why is it that I can pass and return an array of `float`, or `int` in a similar fashion, just fine. and I can pass and return singular structures with `ref` keyword, and I can pass but **not** return and array of `struct`?

*PS*.    I am using Compaq Visual Fortran 6.5 & .NET 3.5
*PS2*.   I appreciate any comments/ideas on this. I am 95% done with my project, and now I run into this issue. The whole point of this project is to use structures as much as possible to reduce the #of arguments passed to functions and retain certain aspects of OOP design.

Comment: I guess this depends on how the run-time is marshalling your values, this shouldn't be a problem, it's always worked fine, I'm mostly amazed to see a FORTRAN/C# hybrid.

Comment: note backtick formatting is not available in titles, unfortunately

Comment: The reality is the modern FORTRAN is easy and fast. I see no reason why not only keep legacy code, but also develop new code in FORTRAN. Of course for GUI and such I leave it to C#/OpenTK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this in the past using a pointer, not an array. I think that your structures are being copied for the P/Invoke call:

```
[DllImport("mathlib.dll")]
static extern void TEST_REF(ValueRef* t, int n);
```

You will need to pin your array before calling the method.

```
fixed (ValueRef* pointer = t)
{
  TEST_REF(pointer, n);
}
```

**Edit:**
Based on the comments the solution is to declare the external as

```
[DllImport("mathlib.dll")]
static extern void TEST_REF([Out] ValueRef[] t, int n);
```

Here is a [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) reference on Marshaling of arrays, and how they *default* to `[In]`.

Comment: I was just about to suggest that... make sure you compile your code with the unsafe flag and mark your methods and scope with the unsafe keyword to otherwise you'll get a bunch of compiler errors.

Comment: When I pass a singular struct byref then it is not copied, but when I pass an array it is copied!?

Comment: A second thing you can try is using the [Out] attribute on the P/Invoke signature.

Comment: The `[Out]` attribute worked. so if you edit your answer I will award it.

Comment: I edited the answer with the correct solution and added a related reference from Microsoft.