# Passing a C# struct with arrays to Fortran without unsafe code

Tags: c#, struct, fortran, intel-fortran

This is kind of a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6231751/380384) question.

I have a [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran) user defined type (`TYPE(contactside)`) that contains some values and some fixed size arrays, as well as an exported function that uses this structure as input arguments. Now I want to call this function from [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). I am able to create fixed sized arrays in a `struct` (`ContactSide`) and it works just fine. I can pass the arrays to fortran

**My question is, is it possible to do this *without* resorting to unsafe code?** With just regular dynamic `C#` arrays `double[] radius` instead of `fixed double radius[MaxSize]`. When I tried it without any `[MarshalAs()]` specifications, I get garbage:

[image: fixed array]
[image: dynamic array]

**Fortan**

```
module contacts
use ISO_C_BINDING
implicit none

    integer, parameter :: max_size = 3600;

    type, bind(c) :: contactside
        INTEGER(c_int) :: n
        REAL(c_double) :: elasticity, poisson
        REAL(c_double) :: radius(max_size), crown(max_size)
    end type

    contains

    !  FUNCTIONS/SUBROUTINES exported from dll:
    subroutine Hertz(load, side1, side2) bind(c)
    implicit none
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::Hertz
    ! Arguments
    REAL(c_double),value,intent(in) :: load
    TYPE(contactside),intent(in)    :: side1, side2

    ! Implementation omitted
    end subroutine Hertz

end module
```

**C#**

```
public unsafe struct ContactSide
{
    const int MaxSize = 3600;
    int size;
    double elasticity, poisson;
    fixed double radius[MaxSize], crown[MaxSize];
    public ContactSide(double radius, double crown) : this(new double[] { radius }, crown) { }
    public ContactSide(double[] radius, double crown)
    {
        this.size=radius.Length;
        fixed (double* ptr1 = this.radius, ptr2 = this.crown)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            {
                ptr1[i]=radius[i];
                ptr2[i]=crown;
            }
        }
        this.elasticity=DefaultElasticity;
        this.poisson=DefaultPoisson;
    }

    public static double DefaultElasticity = 200000;
    public static double DefaultPoisson = 0.3;
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport("FortranContacts.dll", EntryPoint = "hertz", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static void Hertz(double load, ref ContactSide side1, ref ContactSide side2);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContactSide side1 = new ContactSide(8.0, 1200);
        ContactSide side2 = new ContactSide(new double[] { 22, 22.2, 22.8, 24.6, 25.8, 29.3 }, 10000);

        Hertz(1000, ref side1, ref side2);

    }
}
```

and here is the failed attempt at a plain (not unsafe) structure:

```
public struct ContactSide
{
    int size;
    double elasticity, poisson;
    double[] radius, crown;

    public ContactSide(double radius, double crown) : this(new double[] { radius }, crown) { }
    public ContactSide(double[] radius, double crown)
    {
        this.size=radius.Length;
        this.radius=new double[size];
        this.crown=new double[size];
        radius.CopyTo(this.radius, 0);
        this.crown= Enumerable.Repeat(crown, size).ToArray();
        this.elasticity=DefaultElasticity;
        this.poisson=DefaultPoisson;
    }

    public static double DefaultElasticity = 200000;
    public static double DefaultPoisson = 0.3;
}
```

<sub>NOTES: I am using VS2015 with Intel Fortran XE on Win7-64bit</sub>

Comment: After doing that you might be able to pass the derived type by value as well. But I can't say anything about the C# side.

Comment: I added `use ISO_C_BINDING` and declared my types as `INTEGER(c_int)` and `REAL(c_double)`, but nothing changed. Oh, I also changed the declaration to `type, bind(c) :: contactside`.

Comment: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByvalArray, SizeConst = 3600)] is the alternative.  It is a lot more expensive since the pinvoke marshaller must now copy the structure and the arrays.  Safety and efficiency are often opposing goals.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that, but I got an Exception. My goal is specify a dynamic array < 3600 in size and have the marshaler fill in the values on the fortran side. 

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in ConsoleDriver.exe

Additional information: Type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array instance does not match the declared length in the layout."

Comment: @HansPassant if the dynamic arrays are of 3600 size, then the code works as expected with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3600)] double[] radius, crown;`

Comment: It is of course up to you to ensure that the arrays you actually create in your C# code have the expected size.  If they are smaller, larger or null then the pinvoke marshaller just doesn't know how to copy them.

Comment: @francescalus I tried pointers and allocatable arrays, but fortran didn't recognize them as already allocated.

Comment: @HansPassant if you write it up I will award it. Having a full sized dynamic array is an ok solution. I can just use the array `CopyTo()` method to fill the arrays.

Comment: @francescalus add the code snippet to an answer and I'll try it.

Comment: Done.  I'll delete/improve as required when you've had chance to play.

Comment: Just for confirmation, is it not an option to just pass the dynamically allocated C# arrays (like double[] radius in the C# struct) to Fortran subroutines as actual arguments, rather than passing the struct cotaining double[] etc? (because the former seems much easier.)

Comment: @roygvib yes I can do the direct passing of arrays, but I want to avoid it because I end up having 35-50 individual arguments or so. I want to find a way to simplify the code by combining related arrays into structures.

Comment: I installed `mono` on my computer and tried combining C# with gfortran (by googling a lot :) If I define a struct containing bare C-pointers and pass the struct to Fortran routines, I could read/modify the values of the arrays using c_f_pointer(). But if I include double[] etc in the struct, my `mono` failed with segfault (even if I include bare-C pointer together with dynamic C# arrays). So, the compiler seems unhappy with double[] in the struct... Also, if I use bare C-pointers, the code needs to be specified `unsafe`.

Comment: Though not sure, for some Intel-compiler specific ways for interfacing C# and Fortran (other than found on the Internet), it might be useful to ask some Intel forum(s), because they should be experts for it :)

Comment: @roygvib thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

[This is based on ignorance of C# and is more a formatted extended comment.  And wholly untested.]

There is no Fortran derived type which is C interoperable with a C struct type which has a flexible array member.  I'm going to assume that that's essentially what is happening with the C# code.

In particular, the definition

```
type, bind(c) :: contactside
    INTEGER(c_int) :: n
    REAL(c_double) :: elasticity, poisson
    REAL(c_double) :: radius(max_size), crown(max_size)
end type
```

doesn't necessarily allow for arbitrary memory placement of those array components.

What could be possible, depending on other uses in your code of that derived type, is to use pointer components.  Not standard Fortran pointers, but `type(c_ptr)`s:

```
type, bind(c) :: contactside
    INTEGER(c_int) :: n
    REAL(c_double) :: elasticity, poisson
    type(c_ptr) :: radius, crown
end type
```

Later on, those components can be dereferenced in the traditional C interoperability way

```
real(c_double), pointer, dimension(:) :: local_radius, local_crown
...
call c_f_pointer(side1%radius, local_radius, [max_size])
call c_f_pointer(side1%crown, local_crown, [max_size])
```

Comment: Could you use the actual size `contactside%n` in assigning the local arrays?

Comment: `error #6285: There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call.   [C_F_POINTER]`

Comment: For that generic, the arguments should be: a `type(c_ptr)`; a rank-1 array with the pointer attribute; a rank-1 extent-1 array of sizes.  In case I wrote something wrong, could you check those match (or write here the call)?

Comment: And when that `c_f_pointer` does work, yes, the size could be that `n`.  It'll need to be specified as `call c_f_pointer(..., ..., [side1%n])`, though (array as the last argument).

Comment: So the critical point is whether `double[] radius, crown;` represents bare C-pointers in the `struct ContactSide` (in the memory)...? I'm wondering whether they are implemented internally so or as array descriptors (like allocatable arrays in Fortran). Is there any possibility of getting bare C-pointers of allocated regions in the C# side...? (I have no experience with C# either so not sure though...)

Comment: @roygvib's point is the vital one (and one I don't know and can't test): if the memory layout of the C# object is equivalant to a C struct with `int, double, double, *double, *double` then the Fortran derived type with `bind` attribute will be suitable.  If the C# isn't like that then something else will have to be done.  If it's `int, double, double, double[3600], double[3600]` the first (question's) form is the one.

Comment: I am failing to resolve the generic method `c_f_pointer`. My compiler complains that it cannot find the method.

Comment: It's a subroutine in `iso_c_binding`, along with those constants `c_int`, `c_double` and `c_ptr`.  If you're not using an `only` option, on `use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding`, I'm at a loss.  Could you give the compiler, version, and error message?

Comment: I should change `use ISO_C_BINDING` into `use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING`

Comment: I recommend that latter form for intrinsic modules (it makes sure the compiler accesses the intrinsic module rather than a different one with the same name that happens to be available), but unless something strange is going on that should be the thing that makes it work.